# IMEI/ ESN in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, privacy, imei

As I know the Latest Versions Of android stops apps from Accessing IMEI/ESN numbers even with permission. To what I read its Possible only for Pre-loaded apps , or if the app has carrier privileges [Which I have 0 clue about what it means]

The problem is Big OTT platforms Like Netflix Has the ESN number even through there are so many restrictions by android

How do these apps get IMEI/ESN number  out from our  android device?
Is it not possible to replicate the same way of which Netflix Is taking ESN number in my own app?

Comment: "The problem is Big OTT platforms Like Netflix Has the ESN number even through there are so many restrictions by android" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly?

Comment: Ask the Netflix What Data of yours they have . They will send you your ESN number in encrypted form . Also I have Confirmed It on Netflix Support that they Do take ESN number and encrypt with SHA 256 and store :)

Comment: @FawwazAli They may have old ESN numbers from before the change.  Or they may have a UUID on your device and call it ESN.  I wouldn't go by what customer support tells you-  do you really think they have any idea what's actually in there?

Comment: I requested Netflix to send my data of account which i created like 3 days ago ,  they sent my data with esn number

Comment: I would recommend you to try too , make new account try request Netflix for Data they will send you your ESN in encrypted form